# Combinatorics Problem : Additional Clause

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A firm needs to obtain 5 van loads of mineral. The five vans available can
go to any of 11 places of mineral. The basic question
is how many possible ways this can be achieved. The 11 places all have different
kinds of elements in the mineral, so it is always important how many van loads come
from which place. Find the number of ways in each case.

1) It does not matter which van brings which kind of mineral, and any places
can be used by any number of vans. --> 15C5

Unordered selections with repetition is given by : C(n+r-1,r)

The conditions above hold, but additionally there is one of the places that
may only be used at most twice due to lack of supply. (The other places are
unrestricted).

I'm not sure about how to proceed with the additional clause.

Comment: Subtract the number of ways that $3$ or more trucks visit that site.  (Assume $3$ trucks visit that site.  How many ways can the remaining $2$ trucks choose from the $11$ sites?)

Comment: @saulspatz Can you explain more?

Comment: the sit's the same as quasi's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For positive integers $n,r$, by the Stars-and-Bars formula, there are exactly
$$\binom{r+n-1}{n-1}$$
$n$-tuples $(x_1,...,x_n)$ of nonnegative integers satisfying
$$x_1+\cdots +x_n=r$$

For $i\in\{1,...,11\}$, let $x_i$ be the number of vans which load at the $i$-th supply source.

Then for the first question we get the equation
$$x_1+\cdots +x_{11}=5$$
so by the Stars-and-Bars formula, the number of solutions is
$$
\binom{5+11-1}{11-1}=\binom{15}{10}=\binom{15}{5}
$$
matching your answer.

For the second question, we can just subtract the count for those solutions with $x_1\ge 3$.

Writing $x_1=3+y_1$, we get the equation
$$y_1+(x_2+\cdots +x_{11})=2$$
so by the Stars-and-Bars formula, the number of solutions with $x_1\ge 3$ is
$$
\binom{2+11-1}{11-1}=\binom{12}{10}=\binom{12}{2}
$$
hence the number of solutions with $x_1\le 2$ is
$$
\binom{15}{5}-\binom{12}{2}
$$

Comment: Can this be done without the stars and bars method?

Comment: @Emma: Stars-and-Bars is natural for this problem.

Comment: @Emma: If you didn't use Stars-and-Bars for the first question, how did you get ${\large{\binom{15}{5}}}$? Can you edit your question to show how you got it? Note: Since you're a new member, you may not realize that questions posted with no work shown often get closed. To avoid that, always try to some work as part of your posted question.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: @Emma: Thanks for the edit (+1). Note that C(n+r-1,r)=C(r+n-1,n-1), so the formula you used is algebraically equivalent to the Stars-and-Bars formula.

Comment: Yes it is. But I'm finding it hard to understand it using bars and stars method.

Comment: @Emma: You only need to know the formula. Do you understand how the equation
$$x_1+\cdots+x_{11}=5$$
relates to the question?

Comment: yes i get that.Where does this come from  x1=3+y1

Comment: If we assume $x_1\ge 3$, then $x_1=3+y_1$ for some nonnegative integer $y_1$, so we are introducing the new variable $y_1$ to represent the excess of $x_1$ over $3$. Then the original equation
$$x_1+\cdots+x_{11}=5$$
becomes
$$(3+y_1)+(x_2+\cdots+x_{11})=5$$
or equivalently
$$y_1+(x_2+\cdots+x_{11})=2$$
which just another Stars-and-Bars type equation.

Comment: yes. But isn't xi to be the number of trucks wrong as 11 is the no of sources and not trucks?

Comment: @Emma: $x_i$ is the number of truck which load at source $i$. The equation
$$x_1+\cdots+x_{11}=5$$
says that number of trucks is $5$.